# TokenResponse.Properties - OAuth2 authentication Bot Framework

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, botframework

I am implementing a Bot using .NET Bot Framework SDK. For authentication, I am using `Generic OAuth 2` provider - since it is a custom OAuth 2 implementation. I need to some extra parameters once the user login to my application, return back to the Bot.

I thought of using the `TokenResponse.Properties` properties, but it always returns null.

I couldn't find anything useful in the documentation or in Github. I would like to know how to populate the TokenResponse.Properties object from OAuth 2 Token response endpoint.

Comment: can you show your OAuth implementation?

Comment: @G.Dimov I can't share that code. Are you looking for token endpoint code? If you can give me more specific details maybe I can help you.

Comment: @Anuraj without knowing what your OAuth implementation looks like we can't help you. What frameworks/libraries are you using? what have you tried? when are you trying to read the properties. on the callback after the user authenticated?